# How to change image size on featured images in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

I thought I had it all figured out, when of course, the code doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it. I just want to be able to define image sizes in my functions.php file and call them whenever I want from my index.php or single.php. (Excuse all of the comments in the code. I'm following a tutorial trying to learn wordpress and the tutorial doesn't cover the issue of "what if it doesn't work") So currently, the image I'm playing with is 1360x582 and it will resize based on my css, but not according to the functions when I apply them. Any help would be great!

My index.php looks like this:

```
    <?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> | Posted in
            <?php 
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $separator = ", ";
            $output = '';

            if ($categories){

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;
                }

                echo trim($output, $separator); //trim() removes comma from last item//
            }
            ?></p>  

            <?php the_post_thumbnail('small_thumbnail'); ?> <!--featured image-->

<!-- if you want an excerpt to be displayed only if one is manually entered, otherwise show full post:

        <?php if ($post->post_excerpt) { ?>

        <P>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&raquo;</a>
        </p>

        <?php } else {

            the_content();

        } ?>

-->

        <P>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&raquo;</a>
        </p>
        <!-- <?php the_content('Read More...'); ?> -->
    </article>

    <?php endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

functions.php:

```
//Theme Setup

function Theme_setup() {

    //Navigation Menus
    register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
    ));

    //Add Feature Image Support
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 180, 120, true); //width, height, hard (true) or soft crop
    add_image_size('banner-image', 920, 210, true);

}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'Theme_setup');
```

and my single.php looks pretty much the same as my index.php at the moment except that it uses the 'banner-image' on the featured image rather than the 'small-thumnail'

the css I have applied to images is this:

```
/* Image Styles */

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: You might find it's being resized by the `the_post_thumbnail` code as a result of it's outer lying CSS. ie, look at the CSS generated for that function and view what CSS rules are being applied, it will most likely be resizing it :)

Comment: Also, if there are no thumnails of your desired sizes, ie, you've added the new size AFTER the images have been imported into the installation, you'll benefit from regenerating the thumbnails.

Comment: Nothing is being resized, this is my problem: my image size functions aren't working. I don't want the admin to have to physically go into the photos and adjust the thumbnail sizes. I want the theme I'm creating to just do it for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. In the index.php I was using small_thumbnails as opposed to small-thumbnails as I had written in my functions.php page. What a big difference a - makes as opposed to a _. And of course it was a typo solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 180, 120, true);
```

Change the 180 and 120 values (width and height) and you should be good to go.

This resource might also help you:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-featured-image-size

You can also control these values with a plugin called [Simple Image Sizes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/)

Comment: Changing the w/h values doesn't do anything. This is my point: the functions aren't working. The current code I have....
'add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 180, 120, true);'
does't adjust the size of my 1360x582 image as it should. I'd also prefer not to use plugins at the moment as I'm trying to learn how to code and how it all works.